# Replace specific character from an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm self-learning C from a book and currently studying pointers and arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LINES 5
void main()
{
    char* str[LINES];
    str[0] = "hola";
    str[1] = "mundo";
    *(*(str + 0) + 1) = 'Z';
    printf("%c", *(*(str + 0) + 1));
}
```

Here I want to replace 'o' of "hola" with 'Z' but it's not working.
if i remove: 
    *(*(str + 0) + 1) = 'Z';
I get 'o' in the output but how do i replace the character of the string?

Comment: Note that modify a string literal is implemented behavior, and a lot of implementation define them as undefined behavior. If you want to play with string you need to learn to create them first, if available use `strdup()`

Comment: 'strdup()' duplicates a string and returns a pointer to the string but in my code i just want to replace a character. How will 'strdup()' help?

Comment: It's help you to not segfault.

Comment: C have some syntactic sugar for this: instead of  `*(*(str + 0) + 1) = 'Z'`, you may use: `str[0][1] = 'Z'`

Comment: there are only 2 valid signatures for `main()`  they both have a return type of `int`, not `void`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is having [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you are trying to modify a [String Literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal):

```
    str[0] = "hola";
    str[1] = "mundo";
    *(*(str + 0) + 1) = 'Z';   // This is UB
```

From C Standards#6.4.5p7 [String Literals]

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

As suggested by Stargateur, you can use `strdup()` like this:

```
    str[0] = strdup("hola");
    str[1] = strdup("mundo");
```

`strdup()` duplicates the given string. It uses `malloc` to obtain memory for the new string. Make sure to free it once you are done with it, like this:

```
    free (str[0]);
    free (str[1]);
```

Also, using `void` as return type of `main` function is not as per standards. The return type of `main` function should be `int`.

Comment: thanks! it worked!

Comment: Please note however that strdup isn't standard C.